# XSLT to fetch content from a file, where that filename ends with 'demo.xml' only

Tags: xslt

Please suggest to fetch content from group of XMLs out of those, which file name ends with 'demo.xml' by that file I need to fetch the particular element or content. Please suggest, here I used 'collection' method with '*demo.xml' for finding the particular file that ends with word demo.

XML:
2830_demo.xml

```
<article>
  <head>
       <title>Space Technologies</title>
       <author-group>
         <au>Rudramuni</au>
       </author-group>
  </head>
  <body><p>The first para</p></body></article>
```

XSLT:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="varCollection">
       <xsl:copy-of select="collection('file:///D:/Rudramuni/XSLT/Samples/Documents/JVIR?select=*demo.xml;recurse=yes')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
     <xsl:template match="*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="article1">
      <xsl:for-each select="$varCollection">
        <xsl:variable name="a" select="."/>
          <aug><xsl:apply-templates select="$a/article/head/ceauthor-group"/></aug>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? `collection` is XSLT/XPath 2.0 and its argument depends on the XSLT processor. Instead of `<xsl:variable name="varCollection"><xsl:copy-of select="collection('file:///D:/Rudramuni/XSLT/Samples/Documents/JVIR?select=*demo.xml;recurse=yes')"/></xsl:variable>` I strongly suggest to use `<xsl:variable name="varCollection" select="collection('file:///D:/Rudramuni/XSLT/Samples/Documents/JVIR?select=*demo.xml;recurse=yes')"/>`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am using XSLT 2.0. It is working as suggested.

Comment: <xsl:variable name="mspid"><xsl:value-of select="if(doc-available(resolve-uri('*metadata.xml', base-uri(/)))) then doc(resolve-uri('*metadata.xml', base-uri(/)))/item-info/ids/aid else ('Meta data not found')"/></xsl:variable>, here, how to get the content from FILENAME which ends by 'METADATA'. Please suggest